# What version of Firefox is the most reliably secure for everyday browsing? Regular, Beta, Aurora, Nightly?

Tags: security, firefox, browser

My thoughts:

- Nightly is the bleeding edge, so it's more likely any found exploits
  will be fixed on Nightly first. Nightly also would have the latest
  features, some of them security improvements. Yet Nightly is prone to
  be the buggiest, and that opens it up to some zero-day exploits.
- Regular is often more functionally reliable than Beta or Nightly, but can harbor
  vulnerabilities or exploits that were not caught before. Regular is what I believe
  TOR is based on. All of the found exploits in the Beta, Aurora, and Nightly builds would be likely found and fixed before a Regular version is released.
- Aurora and Beta are more the middle ground between Nightly and
  Regular, Aurora being pre-beta.

So my question is, which version would be the most reliably secure for use with everyday browsing?

Will Firefox versions with a severe exploit be fixed sooner with an emergency update?

Comment: Probably better off on superuser, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which build is the most secure depends on the sophistication and determination of the attacker.  For the vast majority of attackers, most of whom have no idea how to write exploits themselves and the rest who don't have the dedication, you are probably better off with the nightly, though not by much if any.  The reason is as you stated, the bug fixes hit the nightly first.

However, with a sophisticated and/or determined attacker, you are much safer with the regular build.  The reason is that developers are *constantly* introducing security holes and vulnerabilities into the nightly builds (not just with FireFox).  Most of these are caught during later testing and fixed before they even hit the beta or the release.  If the attacker knows what they're doing, there are many more opportunities for exploitation if you're running this build.  These are the attackers that can whip up an exploit themselves.  By the time an exploit is releases publicly, it is most assuredly fixed in the regular release.

My personal opinion on the matter is that it isn't worth the pain of dealing with nightly builds unless you are helping with testing and/or development.  Chances are very good that you'll be identically secure either way.